# Twilio Rest api client throw api exception when specifying a region

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I got an Api exception when specified the region id which is "de1" for Germany(Frankfurt) according to twilio.com [regions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/regions). The exception is:

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: api.de1.twilio.com
at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.makeRequest(NetworkHttpClient.java:128)
```

my code for initiate TwilioRestClient:

```
twilioRestClient = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(accountSID, authToken)
            .region("de1")
            .build();
```

if no region is specify I'm able to get proper response.

I'm using twilio version of 7.15.4

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [region document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/regions) you linked to refers to Twilio Client and using the Voice SDK from browsers or native applications. It is not for the REST API and you are getting errors because there is no region subdomain that you can apply to the API URL.

The region attribute for the library is more of an internal tool for Twilio to test the library with development or staging URLs and isn't intended for public use.

Comment: Thank you @philnash for your answer!.  Do you know other way to pass a region from a Twilio Rest api client.  I would like to take advantage of Twilio Region pinning capabilities.

Comment: There isn't region pinning for the REST API. Like I said, the docs you pointed at were for Twilio Client, which is a browser based JavaScript client for making phone calls.

Comment: I've found that com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.conference.ParticipantCreator.java has a region that can be set. in the javadocs it says "Specifies the [region](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132167-How-global-low-latency-routing-and-region-selection-work-for-conferences-and-Client-calls) where Twilio should mix the recorded audio"   .check out the javadocs under (https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-java/7.34.1/index.html)

Comment: Sure, when you [create a conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-region) or a participant to a conference, you can set a region to choose where to mix the audio. This affects conferences only and for the most part you shouldn't need to do this as Twilio will pick the best available region for the call. You can read more about [selecting regions and our global low latency routing here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132167-How-global-low-latency-routing-and-region-selection-work-for-conferences-and-Client-calls). Does that help?